# What's the use of `NOT ON OVERFLOW` in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

From my understanding when using `UNSTRING`, the use of `ON OVERFLOW [INSTRUCTION]` will be useful if there would be an overflow in the use of the `UNSTRING`.

But if there is no overflow, why would you use `NOT ON OVERFLOW [INSTRUCTION]` ?

The only possible utility to the `NOT ON OVERFLOW [INSTRUCTION]` would be to pass an instruction if there is no overflow but what would be the use of that if you already had the expected result from the `UNSTRING` ?

Is there any concrete example of how this could be useful in this example :

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.


WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 WS-VAR1 PIC A(11) VALUE "Hello World".
    01 WS-VAR2 PIC A(5).
    01 WS-VAR3 PIC A(5).
    01 WS-COMPTEUR PIC 9 VALUE 2.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PROCEDURE.
    INTO WS-VAR2 WS-VAR3
    WITH POINTER WS-COMPTEUR
    ON OVERFLOW DISPLAY "This string is too large"
    END-UNSTRING.

    DISPLAY WS-VAR2
    DISPLAY WS-VAR3.
    STOP RUN.
END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

Even when I read IBM documentation, it doesn't give me much explanation as to what could be used in this instance but to display a message ?

IBM Documentation : [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_5.2.0/com.ibm.cobol52.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpsunst.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From my understanding when using UNSTRING, the use of ON OVERFLOW
>   phrase will be useful if there would be an overflow in the use
>   of the UNSTRING.
>
> But if there is no overflow, why would you use NOT ON OVERFLOW
>   phrase ?
>
> The only possible utility to the NOT ON OVERFLOW phrase would
>   be to pass an instruction if there is no overflow but what would be
>   the use of that if you already had the expected result from the
>   UNSTRING ?

In COBOL 74 there was no `NOT ON OVERFLOW` phrase. Therefore, it was necessary to use either a `GO TO` statement or set a flag for testing in an immediately following `IF` statement. The `NOT ON OVERFLOW` phrase and `END-UNSTRING` were added in COBOL 85 to to improve program structure.

For your example, I made some changes to first display `WS-VAR1` then the result of the `UNSTRING`. Note that the `OVERFLOW` condition concerns the number of items and not the length of the text. I ran three tests to show the results

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-VAR1 PIC A(11) VALUE "Hello World".
   01 WS-VAR2 PIC A(5).
   01 WS-VAR3 PIC A(5).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       MOVE SPACE TO WS-VAR2 WS-VAR3
       DISPLAY WS-VAR1
       UNSTRING WS-VAR1
       DELIMITED SPACE
       INTO WS-VAR2 WS-VAR3
       ON OVERFLOW
           DISPLAY
               "Incorrect number of items in WS-VAR1 - expected 2"
       NOT ON OVERFLOW
           DISPLAY WS-VAR2
           DISPLAY WS-VAR3
       END-UNSTRING
       STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

Results:

```
Hello World
Hello
World
--
Hello
Incorrect number of items in WS-VAR1 - expected 2
--
Hello W rld
Incorrect number of items in WS-VAR1 - expected 2
```

As may be seen in the code, `ON OVERFLOW` is used for error processing; `NOT ON OVERFLOW` is used for normal processing. Without the improved structure from `NOT ON OVERFLOW`, normal processing would immediately follow the error processing, unless one used the previously mentioned COBOL 74 type processing.

Note that `DELIMITED ALL SPACE` gives a different result than that shown for one case, above. [Ignore the `--`]

```
--
Hello
Hello

--
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "NOT ON OVERFLOW " statement if you need to call a PROCEDURE to validate this sentence for example SORT-COLORS.

```
MOVE 0 TO COUNT-1.   

UNSTRING COLOR-LIST   
   DELIMITED BY ":" OR "/" OR ALL SPACE   
*DELIMIT-1 and COUNT-1 will hold only   
*the values associated with COLOR-1.   
   INTO COLOR-1   
         DELIMITER IN DELIMIT-1   
         COUNT IN COUNT-1,   
         COLOR-2,   
         COLOR-3,   
         COLOR-4   
   ON OVERFLOW    
      DISPLAY "overflow: unstring colors"   
   NOT ON OVERFLOW   
*do when UNSTRING succeeds.   
      PERFORM **SORT-COLORS**   
END-UNSTRING.   
*COLOR-1 = "RED   "   
*COLOR-2 = "BLUE  "   
*COLOR-3 = "GREEN "   
*COLOR-4 = "YELLOW"   
*DELIMIT-1 = ":  "   
*COUNT-1 = 3 count-1 holds the number of characters in RED
```

You can see more examples on this link https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/acucorpproducts/docs/v6_online_doc/gtman3/gt36141.htm

On practice if youy need to discovery if your command(unsting) are executed with sucess withou a IF you can use this statement to define it.

An example using your aplication

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.


WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 WS-VAR1 PIC A(11) VALUE "Hello World".
    01 WS-VAR2 PIC A(5).
    01 WS-VAR3 PIC A(5).
    01 WS-COMPTEUR PIC 9 VALUE 2.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PROCEDURE.
    INTO WS-VAR2 WS-VAR3
    WITH POINTER WS-COMPTEUR
    ON OVERFLOW 
        PERFORM RT-SEND-ERROR-MAIL
    NOT ON OVERFLOW 
        PERFORM RT-SEND-SUCESS-MAIL
    END-UNSTRING.

    DISPLAY WS-VAR2
    DISPLAY WS-VAR3.
    STOP RUN.
END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```